# Oracle MYSQL EXECUTION PLAN

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between how Oracle executes query above and below.

First query:

```
SELECT 
D.DName AS Department,
E3.Name AS Manager,
P.pTitle AS Project,
E2.Name AS Supervisor,
E2.Name AS Employee,
W.Hours
FROM
Department D,
Employee E1,
Employee E2,
workson W,
project P,
Employee E3
WHERE
D.Dnumber = P.Dnumber
    AND P.Pnumber = W.Pnumber
    AND W.Enumber = E1.Enumber
    AND E1.Supervisor = E2.ENumber
    AND D.Manager = E3.ENumber
ORDER BY P.pTitle;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
D.DName AS Department,
E3.Name AS Manager,
P.pTitle AS Project,
E2.Name AS Supervisor,
E2.Name AS Employee,
W.Hours
FROM
Department D,
Employee E1,
Employee E2,
workson W,
project P,
Employee E3
WHERE
D.Dnumber = P.Dnumber
    AND P.Pnumber = W.Pnumber
    AND W.Enumber = E1.Enumber
    AND E1.Supervisor = E2.ENumber
    AND D.Manager = E3.ENumber
 ORDER BY E3.Name;
```

How is the execution plan different for the above two codes in my sql? will it be different or will it stay the same? How will the execution plan be for the above codes? Are they any different from one another?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `java`, `mysql` and `oracle`; however, you only mention Oracle in your question's text, and there doesn't seem to be anything about Java in the question. Please remove the inappropriate tags.

Comment: The `order by` clause is diferent, so the execution plans is different. Other than that, you should probably give more context to your question, else it is hard to provide a meaningful answer here.

Comment: I want help with the execution plan

Comment: The execution plan for a query is very specific of context: schema definitions, engine version, table size, server configuration, etc.

To understand a particular case, should use EXPLAIN <query>; sentences on each query, and compare the execution plan that your mysql instance is giving to those queries. So, if you want help after doing that, please add the output of those commands to the question. Regards.